# PHP Shortcode - How to accept category argument for WP blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, shortcode

I have some PHP to show display Blog Post Snippets by category in Wordpress, but I can't get it to accept an argument for the category.

The shortcode displays all Blog Posts no matter what I put in the 'pageCategory' portion of the shortcode.

However, it does show posts for specific categories if I hardcode 'pageCategory' => ' ' to a specific category.

How do I get this function to accept variable categories?

```
function wpb_postsbycategory($atts) {
    
     $a = shortcode_atts( array(
 'pageCategory' => ''
 ), $atts );
    
    
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'category_name' => $a['pageCategory'], 
    'posts_per_page' => 15 
) ); 
   
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            }
            }
    } else {
    // no posts found
 $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
}
$string .= '</ul>';
   
return $string;
   
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');
```

Shortcode

```
[categoryposts pageCategory='aCategory']
```

Comment: Read this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/#comment-3820

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For anyone struggling with the same issue, I removed all of my camelCase and replaced it with underscores

Example:

From
`'category_name' => $a['pageCategory'],`
To
`'category_name' => $a['page_category'],`